# Why a simple Java RMI call is causing CPU spike and GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I created a simple RMI server and client using the steps and programs mentioned at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remote-method-invocation-in-java/

When I profile (using YourKit) the client program (ClientRequest.java), I see a spike in CPU (around 10% usage) and I also see a GC. I am curious about why this simple program is causing a GC. There is plenty of heap memory still available.

I can see "RMI RenewClean" and "RMI Scheduler" threads in the profiler. Are these threads causing the GC? I am wondering why a simple RMI call is causing GC. Could someone please provide some input? I attached YourKit snapshot here:

http://www.mediafire.com/file/jnlxk4mjv69xecs/ClientRequest-2019-10-30.snapshot/file

I tried searching on internet but couldn't find anything related.

Comment: There's nothing "simple" about an RMI call, except maybe the way it appears to a developer.

Comment: Your remote reference prevents the garbage collection of the referent on a different machine. Since the usual trigger doesn’t work (i.e. you don’t know whether the remote machine is low on memory), RMI periodically forces a garbage collection.